# How to switch between windows in SSH Terminal?

Tags: vim, ssh

I've just started to use VIM on a SSH server (without graphical display i.e ssh -x). 
I know I can open multiple vim files by either `:sp` , `vim -o` or `:tabnew` but, I've two set of files which make logical sense to have them on separate vim windows so I do the following `vim file1.txt file2.txt -p; vim file3.txt file4.txt -p` which creates two windows. I want to know is it possible to switch between those two windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two Vim instances and the second one put the first one in the background.

You'll need to use your shell's job control commands:

```
<C-z> to suspend the current job
fg    to switch to the latest background job
fg2   to switch to the second latest background job
jobs  to list all current jobs
```

In your situation, a single `<C-z>` will suspend the second Vim and show the first one. Another `<C-z>` will suspend the first Vim and get you back to your shell, where you will be able to use `fg` and `jobs`.

But you should probably try [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/), though, those programs will give you a lot more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use windows, like (after having file1.txt and file2.txt open):

```
:new file3.txt
:e file3.txt
```

and then switch between the windows via CTRL+W?